# How to save a field to which long id will be converted in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, jpa

I followed this link:
https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-map-calculated-properties-with-hibernate-generated-annotation/

Here is my source code:

```
private String firstName;

private String lastName;

private String middleName1;

private String middleName2;

private String middleName3;

private String middleName4;

private String middleName5;

@Generated( value = GenerationTime.ALWAYS )
@Column(columnDefinition =
    "AS CONCAT(" +
    "   COALESCE(firstName, ''), " +
    "   COALESCE(' ' + middleName1, ''), " +
    "   COALESCE(' ' + middleName2, ''), " +
    "   COALESCE(' ' + middleName3, ''), " +
    "   COALESCE(' ' + middleName4, ''), " +
    "   COALESCE(' ' + middleName5, ''), " +
    "   COALESCE(' ' + lastName, '') " +
    ")")
private String fullName;
```

It uses other `string` fields to generate that `fullname` field.

What i want is something different.

I have an auto increment id field in spring boot class:

```
private long id //or it can be int, does not matter
```

I have also another field, which must be unique and alphanumeric.

```
private String code;
```

This field will have 6 alphanumeric (upper or lower case does not matter).

Is it possible to save this field auto while a new object created, with such a method?

```
Long.toString("id_field_value",36);
```

Actually, it gives:

```
0 -> 0
1 -> 1
10 -> A
```

So, when first object is created, id will be 1.

Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you want to generate the code field based on id?

Comment: @EugenCovaci yes. Both are unique so no need to use other methods to generate another alphanumeric. id is already incremented and autogenerated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can be possible.

You can generate your code in a different method, that will return your alphanumeric value and set the `code` property to the return value of your random method

Comment: No i want id value to be converted to that field. Not another

Comment: I'm not clear on what you are asking but you can use `.flush()` to get the id of the persisted object.

Comment: It will autosave id. For example the id is 9000. code field will be long value of 9000. It will be saved auto

Answer (score 0):

Try the following annotations on your long field:

```
@Id   
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
@SequenceGenerator(name="id_sequence", sequenceName="id_sequence", allocationSize=1)
private long id
```

Save this persistence object using hibernate. Make sure you have a sequence with the specified name in your schema.

Schema can be created by:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE schema_name.id_sequence
    INCREMENT BY 1
    MINVALUE 1
    MAXVALUE 9223372036854775807
    START 1;
```

You can refer to the [link](https://github.com/AbhijeetSakhalkar/SprintBoot/blob/master/src/main/java/com/example/demo/persistence/Product.java) incase you need some referance

Comment: It is nonid field.

Comment: I believe if you remove @Id annotation and keep everything as it is now, things will work fine.